# How to call an instance inside class methods?

Tags: python, class

```
class Purse:
    def __init__(
        self,
        owner,
        currency="USD",
    ):
        if currency not in ("EUR", "USD"):
            raise ValueError
        self.owner = owner
        self.__money = 0.00  
        self.currency = currency

        def withdraw_money(self, howmany):
    if self.__money - howmany < 0:
        raise ValueError("not enough balance")
    self.__money = self.__money - howmany
    return howmany

    def add_money(self, howmany):
```

#How to check if instance attribute != another_instance attribute to raise ValueError?

```
        self.__money = self.__money + howmany
        return howmany
```

)

#So

```
name1.add_money(name2.withdraw_money(value))
```

should raise ValueError, if name1.currency, for instance is "USD" and name2.currency is "EUR"

Comment: Please fix your indentation. `if self.__money - howmany < 0:` needs to be indented inside the method.

Comment: If you want to compare with another instance, you need to pass that instance as a function parameter.

Comment: When `name1.add_money(name2.withdraw_money(value))` runs, the interpreter will first run `name2.withdraw_money(value)` and then pass its return value along to `name1.add_money`.  That means that if you need some context about how the function was called (e.g. what `Purse` instance it was called from, or which currency that instance was using), you must `return` that context in `withdraw_money`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a separate `transfer_money()` method for this. It will take the destination instance, and you can compare the currencies.

```
def transfer_money(dest, howmany):
    if self.currency != dest.currency:
        raise ValueError('source and destination use different currencies')
    dest.add_money(self.withdraw_money(howmany))
```